# Disable DEBUG trap inside pipes

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on several repos using vim && terminal. As I often find myself asking on which repo/branch I am, I thought I could have the shell telling me this each time I issue a (set of) command(s).

A straightforward way is to use `trap 'git config --get remote.origin.url'  DEBUG`.

It does the job, but has an annoying side-effect: The trap gets triggered by all command in a pipe. Hence, the repo url gets printed several times.

```
$ls | echo yes
git@gitlab.com:development.git
git@gitlab.com:development.git
yes
```

How can I make so that trap gets triggered only by the first (or last ) command in a pipe?

I tried using test conditions like `[ -p /dev/stdout ] or [ -p /dev/stdin]` but that doesn't work:

```
$trap -- '{ [ -p /dev/stdout ] && return ;} || echo knock' DEBUG
$ls | echo yes
knock
knock
yes
```

Notice that for both commands stdout seems to be attached to a pipe:

```
$trap -- '[ -p /dev/stdout ] ; echo -p: $? ' DEBUG
$ls | echo yes
-p: 1
-p: 1
yes
```

However, this condition does identify the pipe when issued interactively

```
${ [ -p /dev/stdout ] ; echo A-p: $? >/dev/stderr ;} | { [ -p /dev/stdout ] ; echo B-p: $? ;}
A-p: 0
B-p: 1
```

I could not identify on `help trap` any flag that could help.

Is this even possible?

Comment: The traditional solution is to use PROMPT_COMMAND or PS1. Is there a reason you're not doing that?

Comment: I didn't know about prompt command, but I also didn't want to alter my prompt everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend that you only run functions from `trap`, not multi-statement scripts (this is for simplicity).

Second, the DEBUG trap is not a great way to do this. I do not know for sure how to disable DEBUG on pipes, or even if you can. However, there may be another way to solve your problem.

Third and last, you can treat PROMPT_COMMAND as a script to be run whenever the prompt is about to be displayed (it runs once after your pipeline but before PS1 is displayed).

So:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND+=$'\nls | echo yes'
```

This will add a command to the script and run it at what I believe is the time you want. This is not only less hacky than abusing DEBUG, it's far more efficient.

You may wish to also look at `git-prompt.sh` from the git project: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
This is the standard solution for displaying your current branch while within a git repo. It provides the shell function `__git_ps`, which is normally used from PS1 but could also be used from PROMPT_COMMAND.

This function will print the current branch in parentheses, but will also print other pertinent information if relevant: whether a rebase or cherry-pick is in progress, whether you are in a detached HEAD state, and many more.

Comment: I will have to check out git prompt...My actual trap calls a function defined in ~/.bashrc. I just posted what I identified as the issue for me using this trap solution.

Comment: Curious: why do think `trap <function> DEBUG` is abusing this feature?

Comment: PROMPT_COMMAND is nice in that it does not lead to duplicated lines when issuing a pipe, and has the added feature it prints the return of that command _after_  the cli  returns. However, it has the side effect of executing the command even after pressing return w/o any command (empty line). I may take this as a compromise before looking further into the git solution as it is still better than my trap. Thanks!

Comment: The DEBUG trap is intended for debugging. It has a major performance impact. It also does not always fire when you might think it should, sometimes more often (as you discovered) and sometimes less often. DEBUG runs even in scripts, but PROMPT)_COMMAND will not. Its behavior is also still in motion. Consider: What happens if you `trap my-func DEBUG` and then execute multiple statements inside the function.
I have abused DEBUG for xterm titlebar updating purposes, among other things, and the result is slow and painful. If you can avoid having it run all the time you should.